# Doctype for html email

Tags: html-email, doctype

Which DOCTYPE is the right one for HTML email?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: That depends entirely on the content of the document itself.  Use whatever doctype matches the content.

Comment: I am using the first one. I read somewhere right doctype is "Transitional" . I am not sure whether it is HTML 4.01 Transitional or XHTML 1.0 Transitional. But most of the html email tutorials are using the second one that is XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

Comment: The doctype simply informs the parser about how to interpret the HTML that follows.  Use 4.01 if the HTML document itself is 4.01, XHTML if it's XHTML, etc.  It doesn't have anything to do with email in particular.

Comment: I would love to see an answer that reflect the current state of major mail clients here in 2023 or 'Can we use <!DOCTYPE html> yet?'

Answer (score 7):

There is only minor differences these days in DOCTYPE declarations in html email.  Although only minor, it is still recommended to test your emails via Email on Acid or Litmus or any other testing software prior to a send to ensure cross client compatibility and to find any unforeseen quirks.

The larger issues comes with if you do not declare a doctype or body tag, it can really screw up different parts of the email on certain clients.

The most popular DOCTYPE nowadays is the HTML 5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE HTML>`) which is used with very little hiccups. The most popular/safest doctype used to be the `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` doctype. This can still be used, but may limit different capabilities of your email, as it is referencing an older version of HTML.

See this forum post in litmus for more in-depth information on this: https://litmus.com/community/discussions/39-explanation-of-doctype-html-attributes-and-meta-tags-in-email-head

Answer (score 4):

This is what I use.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

I code emails daily and this came as the header that exact  target (salesforce) provided us. Our company has sister brands and this what they all use as well so I'm assuming this is standard.

Answer (score 0):

More primitive email readers cannot handle DOCTYPE at all, and instead either strip it completely out of the email, or just remove the string "!DOCTYPE" and leave the rest of the HTML intact. You wind up seeing weird things like this at the beginning of the emails:

> < HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
>   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

...because the word !DOCTYPE was removed, but not the rest, and since it did not remove the space, it displayed the broken code to the reader.

The rest of the email will usually display just fine.

While this obviously is a programming error by the writer of the script, I have seen a lot of scripts with this same exact error. It's usually because they are simply stripping out HTML tags and not allowing !DOCTYPE.

Email clients seem to be able to process your email without it unless you are using a different character set than the user, and sometimes stumble when you declare it.