# Return HTML string from php function and mail it using phpMailer

Tags: php

What i want to accomplish is:

- call a function from a file
- that function returns me a variable with the correct html template
- pass the return of this function to another function and use it as body in phpMailer.

I have a page **request.php** where i call **getEmailTemplate()** from **ManageEmailtemplates.php** to get the correct html template and store it to variable: $body=getEmailtemplate();

```
  function getEmailTemplate(){
     $template='<html><body> html data </body> </html>'; 
     return $template;
  }
```

then i want to pass this variable to another file **cls_mailHandler.php** and use it as body to email.

```
function NewRequestMail($template){ 
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
   $mail->Body    = $template;
   $mail->isHTML(true); 
}
```

The problem is that when i try this way my emails sent i can see them on my mobile but on mail client on browser nothing show up(gmail, hotmail...)

If i change this **$body=getEmailtemplate();** to this **$body="'".getEmailtemplate()."'";** then in hotmail shows up html content with the **'** at the beginning and at the end. But gmail nothing.

Is there any specific way that i have to pass html data inside variable and use them?

thank you

Comment: use doctype and meta tags

Comment: for doctypes check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319889/doctype-for-html-email

Comment: Try to print out `$template` inside `NewRequestMail`

Comment: Checkout if this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140263/phpmailer-sending-html-code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590065/how-to-use-variables-in-phpmailer-message-body

Comment: @CybervisionInternational i already used what the first link suggested.

Comment: @DavitHuroyan i try with the doctypes but i had the same result. If i pass my variable without **'** then i can see the content only on my mobile. if i use **'** then i can see the content on my hotmail with the **'** and the start and the end but not on my gmail

Answer (score 0):

Try this format please, I checked it and it works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head> <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'> <title>Jetbull Affiliates </title> 

<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1'> 
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;'> 
</head>
<body>
<!-- Content here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your sample and works for me too. I don't know if  the Doctyte is the answer but I think that something in my html is what created this problem(i got my html from an email template creator). When i delete all the code for IE support in my html worked fine.